# XMLUtil not showing details of mismatched xml attributes

Tags: xml, testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am using QTP's `XMLUtil` to compare 2 xmls. Everything works fine except if there are any differences in tag elements. For example,

In XML1, the tag is:

```
<DirtyBondPrice PriceType="Price" Currency="GBP" Weight1="02">110</DirtyBondPrice>
```

In XML2, the tag is

```
<DirtyBondPrice PriceType="Price" Currency="USD" Weight1="02">110</DirtyBondPrice>
```

Code snippet

```
booleanResult = objXML1.Compare(objXML2, objResultsXML)
objResultsXML.SaveFile "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\6.xml"
```

So the difference is show as follows

```xml
<mic_root state="mismatch">
  <RepoTrade state="mismatch">
    <SpecificDetail state="mismatch">
      <DirtyBondPrice mic_elemA_attr="%s=&quot;%s&quot;;%s=&quot;%s&quot;" mic_elemB_attr="%s=&quot;%s&quot;;%s=&quot;%s&quot;" state="mismatch" />
    </SpecificDetail>
  </RepoTrade>
</mic_root>
```

What I was expecting (and according to QTP help file what should be displayed):

```
<DirtyBondPrice mic_elemA_attr="Currency="GBP"" mic_elemB_attr="Currency="USD"" state="mismatch" />
```

Is this a bug in QTP's XMLUtil API?

**Update**
Are there UFT users out there who can verify if this problem is reproduceable with UFT? Because if it is a QTP bug, we won´t have a chance to get a patch developed...

Comment: I just discovered the same. Wtf. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 11 build 1018 with patches 00709, 00078, 000444, 00090, 00051, 00057, 00123. (The long patch list indicates how many bugs in 11 needed fixes. I´ll add the UFT tag and extend your question. maybe UFT users can verify if they see the problem, too.)